# Why aren't these JSX <li> items rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this nested object:

```
 const data = {
    username: "username",
    date: "16/01/2021",
    time: "10:30",
    end: "11:30",
    equipment: {
        thing1: 0,
        thing2: 0,
        thing3: 0,
    },
    cost: 25.00
}
```

I want to create a li item for each key/value pair as part of a functional React component using JSX.

The rest of the code looks like this:

```
const entries = Object.entries(data)

return (
  <div>
     <h4>Please review your booking</h4>
     <ul>
       {
         entries && typeof entries === 'object' ? 
         entries.map(entry => {
           if (typeof entry[1] ==='object') {
             let nestedObj = Object.entries(entry[1])
              nestedObj.map(entry => { 
                return <li>{entry[0]}: {entry[1]}</li>)
              }
            } else {<li>{entry[0]}: {entry[1]}</li>}
         })
         : <li></li>
       }
      </ul>
   </div>
)
```

It looks to me like it should work. Tested the logic with console logs instead of li's and it was fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because object exists, therefore you're rendering `entries.map` and not `<li></li>`

Comment: but then shouldn't it still render some <li>'s then?

Comment: Sorry, not if object exists, but it looks like entries always exists, and entries is always of type object. Hard to know without seeing the rest of your code, sorry. But you define entries right above the return, so it makes sense that it always exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors: you're not `return`ing from the `else`, and you have an extra closing paren.

```
 return (
    <div>
      <h4>Please review your booking</h4>
      <ul>
        {
          entries && typeof entries === 'object' ? 
            entries.map(entry => {
              if (typeof entry[1] ==='object') {
                let nestedObj = Object.entries(entry[1])
                nestedObj.map(entry => { 
                  // removed extra paren here
                  return <li>{entry[0]}: {entry[1]}</li>
                })
              } else {
                // added return here
                return <li>{entry[0]}: {entry[1]}</li>
              }
            })
            : <li></li>
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't return the value in the `map` function.

```
if (typeof entry[1] ==='object') {
   let nestedObj = Object.entries(entry[1])
      return nestedObj.map(entry => { 
         return <li>{entry[0]}: {entry[1]}</li>)
      }
} else {
  return (<li>{entry[0]}: {entry[1]}</li>)
}
```